# RestFB java / https "me" request is slow on GCE

Tags: java, https, google-compute-engine, restfb

I am having issue with restfb? running on Google Compute Engine.
Request for "me" takes around 15 seconds which is quite slow.
On the other hand fetching friends is much fuster and takes les

Mine code looks as follows:

```
public User getUser(String userAccessToken) {
    DefaultFacebookClient facebookClient = ...;
    Parameter fields = Parameter.with("fields", "id,name,email,birthday,age_range,gender,locale,first_name,last_name,picture.width(200)");
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    User fbUser = facebookClient.fetchObject("me", User.class, fields);
    long end = System.nanoTime();
    log.info("FacebookService: me took ", new NiceTime("", end - start));
    return fbUser;
}
```

Could someone give me hint how to slow the issue ?

Comment: is the result comparable? and can you please try to connect to the graph api with plain java without restfb to ensure that the traffic is not limited in general ...